# Parsing JSON values inside an array android

Tags: android, json

this the JSON data that i want to parse in my application:

```
{
  "viewdeal":[
  {
     "viewdeal1":{
        "teetimeId":"33",
        "golfcourseId":"127",
        "offers":"descount of $2",
        "time":"8\/7\/pm",
        "amount":"90",
        "month":"august",
        "year":"2012",
        "date":"21",
        "day":"monday",
        "created_date":"0",
        "golfcourse_name":"SilverHorn Golf Club"
     },
     "msz":"Book"
   }
 ]
}
```

The code that i am using to parse the JSON data is:

```
JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONfromUrl("http://mygogolfteetime.com/iphone/viewdeal/127");
JSONArray viewdeal = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VWDL);
                vwdlsList.clear();
                for(int i=0; i<viewdeal.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject v1 = viewdeal.getJSONObject(i);
                    msz = v1.getString(TAG_MSZ);
                    viewdeal1 = v1.getString(TAG_VWDL1);
                    JSONArray viewdeal1 = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VWDL1); 
                    for(int j=0; j<viewdeal1.length(); j++)
                    {
                        JSONObject v2 = viewdeal.getJSONObject(j);
                        teetimeId = v2.getString(TAG_TTIMEID);
                        golfcourseId = v2.getString(TAG_GLFCRSID);
                        offers = v2.getString(TAG_OFR);
                        time = v2.getString(TAG_TIME);
                        amount = v2.getString(TAG_AMNT);
                        month = v2.getString(TAG_MNTH);
                        year = v2.getString(TAG_YEAR);
                        date = v2.getString(TAG_DATE);
                        day = v2.getString(TAG_DAY);
                        created_date = v2.getString(TAG_CRTDATE);
                        golfcourse_name = v2.getString(TAG_GLFCRSNAME);
                    }

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_TTIMEID, teetimeId);
                    map.put(TAG_GLFCRSID, golfcourseId);
                    map.put(TAG_MSZ, msz);
                    map.put(TAG_OFR, offers);
                    map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
                    map.put(TAG_AMNT, amount);
                    map.put(TAG_MNTH, month);
                    map.put(TAG_YEAR, year);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                    map.put(TAG_DAY, day);
                    map.put(TAG_CRTDATE, created_date);
                    map.put(TAG_GLFCRSNAME, golfcourse_name);

                    vwdlsList.add(map);
                }
            }
```

In the above code i am able to parse the value of msz and viewdeal1 but when i try to parse the remaining values that are in the viewdeal1 i receive the following message in my LogCat:

```
08-22 12:03:46.034: V/GoGolf(1178): org.json.JSONException: No value for viewdeal1
```

How can I parse the remaining values that are in the viewdeal1..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) may helps you.

Comment: Didn't take a look at that example?

Comment: [This one](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: sir I have followed this tutorial and when i change the code to this one: JSONObject viewdeal1 = viewdeal.getJSONObject(TAG_VWDL1); it gives following  errors: "change the type of TAG_VWDL1 to int" and "change getJSONObject(..) to optJSONObject(..)" and "change getJSONObject(..) to toJSONObject(..)"  .... How to over come these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
nParser jParser = new JsonParser();
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONfromUrl("http://mygogolfteetime.com/iphone/viewdeal/127");
JSONArray viewdeal = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VWDL);
                vwdlsList.clear();
                for(int i=0; i<viewdeal.length(); i++)
                {

             ---->> **JSONObject v1= viewdeal.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("viewdeal1");**

                         .....
                         .....      
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your asking for the "viewdeal1" key twice:

```
     viewdeal1 = v1.getString(TAG_VWDL1);
     JSONArray viewdeal1 = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VWDL1);
```

The second line is correct you want it as an **object**, the first list should be deleted.

```
     JSONObject viewdeal1 = json.getJSONObject(TAG_VWDL1);
```

---

If you check your LogCat it tell's you the exact line:

GoGolf(1178)

which is GoGolf.java line 1178, [turn on line numbers in your eclipse](http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/line-number-eclipse-1.png) and I am guessing that line 1178 is `viewdeal1 = v1.getString(TAG_VWDL1);` is it saying `No value for viewdeal1` because it can't find a `String` that matches that key because it is a `JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

hi here `viewdeal1` is not an `array` its an `object`

change

```
JSONArray viewdeal1 = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VWDL1);
```

to

```
JSONObject viewdeal1 = json.getJSONObject(TAG_VWDL1);
```

and delete

```
viewdeal1 = v1.getString(TAG_VWDL1);
```

and please remove the for loop as there is no `array` in `viewdeal1`

a `json array` starts with `'['` bracket

Comment: sir I have changed the 

JSONArray viewdeal1 = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VWDL1);
to
JSONObject viewdeal1 = json.getJSONObject(TAG_VWDL1);

and also deleted viewdeal1 = v1.getString(TAG_VWDL1);

But still i am getting the same error in my LogCat..

can you please be more specific as I am new to JSON parsing..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONfromUrl("http://mygogolfteetime.com/iphone/viewdeal/127");
 JSONArray viewdeal = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VWDL);
            vwdlsList.clear();

for(int i=0; i<</>viewdeal.length(); i++)
          {
                JSONObject v1 = viewdeal.getJSONObject(i);
                msz = v1.getString(TAG_MSZ);
JSONObject v2 = v1.getJSONObject(TAG_VWDL1);
 teetimeId = v2.getString(TAG_TTIMEID);
                    golfcourseId = v2.getString(TAG_GLFCRSID);
                    offers = v2.getString(TAG_OFR);
                    time = v2.getString(TAG_TIME);
                    amount = v2.getString(TAG_AMNT);
                    month = v2.getString(TAG_MNTH);
                    year = v2.getString(TAG_YEAR);
                    date = v2.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    day = v2.getString(TAG_DAY);
                    created_date = v2.getString(TAG_CRTDATE);
                    golfcourse_name = v2.getString(TAG_GLFCRSNAME);
 }

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_TTIMEID, teetimeId);
                map.put(TAG_GLFCRSID, golfcourseId);
                map.put(TAG_MSZ, msz);
                map.put(TAG_OFR, offers);
                map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
                map.put(TAG_AMNT, amount);
                map.put(TAG_MNTH, month);
                map.put(TAG_YEAR, year);
                map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                map.put(TAG_DAY, day);
                map.put(TAG_CRTDATE, created_date);
                map.put(TAG_GLFCRSNAME, golfcourse_name);

                vwdlsList.add(map);
            }
        }
```